Specify geo location of a web page
I have a web app that lists events. Every event has a location. And each event has its own web page describing that event.
Is there a way to specify the location of the event in the meta data of the web page for that event?
My goal is that Google then knows a user is in Denver and so will show them matching searches for event pages in the Denver area, but not show them events in the Chicago area.

Google specifies metadata for webpages on a bunch of subjects. This includes events and that metadata includes an address. This is the way to provide this information, and more to search engines.
